# Why is submit state not updating after change of input right away?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please help me wit this code. I am struggling to update state right away after input is inserted. I was trying to do it with onSubmit method at least to sync input === submit after clicking on Button but still no luck as per console log.

See console picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBYdy.png)

How should I do it?

```
import React from 'react';
import './Search.css'; 

const results = ["Balaton", "Zamardi", "Sound", "Madarsko", "Sziget", "Hungary"]

class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: '',
            submit: ''
        };
        this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onInput(event) {
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value,
            submit: this.state.input});
        console.log(this.state.input)
        console.log(this.state.submit)
    }

    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (results.includes(this.state.input)){
            return alert("This is correct")
        } else {
            return alert("This not correct")
        }

    }
    render() {


        return(
            <div>
                <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.input} placeholder="Our great memory" onChange={this.onInput}/>
                    <button type="submit">Try that!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Search;
```

Comment: why are your values not held in the class' state value?

Comment: It was giving me error this error ```'const' can only be used in a .ts file.``` so I have put it outside of class. But maybe good point I have started with react few weeks ago

Comment: That's not making a whole lot of sense, but ok

Comment: `setState({})` is asynchronous in nature. You won't see the updated value in console.log after setting it.

Comment: @AtinSingh OK. Actually this code works somehow.. Then I dont need to worry about not seeing in console.

Comment: @VojtechLitavsky, do the console.log outside onInput and you will see the new changes

Comment: iirc, `setState` takes a call back that can be added as an additional parameter to be called after the update has occurred

Comment: @VojtechLitavsky exactly.. everything should work fine i guess, just your console.logs won't work. If you want to see correct logs then you can use callbacks of setstate.

Comment: Appreciate that guys! @AtinSingh ,Besart ,Jhecht !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote your component for readability,  I believe you error is simply that setstate is async. This means that when you tried to set the state of submit at the same time as input, submit would always be one behind. By adding the callback in onInput after input has been set you should get the correct value ready to be submitted

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const results = ["Balaton", "Zamardi", "Sound", "Madarsko", "Sziget", "Hungary"]

class Search extends Component {
        state = {
            input: '',
            submit: ''
        };
   // Added callback after input setstate
    onInput = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value}, () => this.setState({submit: this.state.input));
        console.log(this.state.input)
        console.log(this.state.submit)
    }

    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (results.includes(this.state.input)){
            return alert("This is correct")
        } else {
            return alert("This not correct")
        }

    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input 
                    type="text" 
                    value={this.state.input} 
                    placeholder="Our great memory" 
                    onChange={this.onInput}/>
                    <button type="submit">Try that!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onInput(event) {
        this.setState({
            input: event.target.value,
            submit: event.target.value});,() =>
        console.log(this.state.input)
        console.log(this.state.submit)
 }
```

This will let you see the correct values in log too.

Your submit state doesn't update as you assign the old value of `this.state.input` to it rather you should assign `event.target.value`.